Why is $z(x,y) = x^{1.5}y^{0.7}$ not differentiable?
If $z(x,y) = x^{1.5}y^{0.7}$, why is $z$ not differentiable?
I use the definition and manage to make it zero times bounded
using $(x-y)^2\geq 0$ enter image description here
Some told me it's because of the domain of definition, but I tried to do even powers and it still comes out to me as zero and it's not differentiable.
Something like that $x^{1.6}y^{0.6}$.

More detail is needed. Things are unclear as they stand. It is also preferred that questions be self contained without referring to external pictures.
Also  differentiability could fail for different reasons depending on where it is being assessed. At 0, a function fails to be continuous when composed since negative numbers can't be raised to fractional powers over the reals.

@נדב What do you mean by "zero*blocked"?

...ואם אתה מתכוון לתחוּם של הפונקציה אז הביטוי הנכונה היא

"domain", not "field of definition"

The derivative
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 0.7 x^{1.5}y^{-0.3}
$$
is not defined when $y = 0$, since this requires division by zero.

Please don’t use
images instead of typing your formulas

Your formula proves that $z$ (defined for $x,y\ge0$) is differentiable at $(0,0)$, essentially because $1.5+0.7>1$.
But it is not differentiable at $(x,0)$ for $x\ne0$, essentially because $0.7<1$: $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}(x,0)=\lim_{y\to0^+}x^{1.5}y^{-0.3}$ does not exist.

Can you show me a paht of x,y  that not going to zero?

What do you mean? At $(0,0)$, $z$ is continuous (even differentiable!).
